# Python - Choose directory that contains a specific string

Tags: python, string, directory, contains, listdir

The following code prints a list of directories that all happen to contain a 3 letter code, Example:

//Server/Jobs/2016\AAM - 'areallylongfilename'/

//Server/Jobs/2016\CLM - 'areallylongfilename'/

//Server/Jobs/2016\COO - 'areallylongfilename'/

```
import os
basepath = '//Server/Jobs/2016'
for fname in os.listdir(basepath):
    path = os.path.join(basepath, fname)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        print(path)
```

How can I get one directory from the list based on the 3 letter code?

Comment: This code doesn't return *list of directories that all contain a 3 letter code*, but paths of all the directories present within `basepath`.  And do you mean to print one path from the printed paths? If yes, any specifix path or random path?

Comment: yes I'd like to print one path if it contains the 3 letter code I enter. I'm making a Tkinter application for moving files from a source into one of the directories in the //Server/Jobs/2016 path. The application asks for a three letter code in order to choose a destination directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
basepath = '//Server/Jobs/2016'
asked_name = 'COO'
if len(asked_name) != 3:
        print "Expected 3 letter code, got:", asked_name
else:
        for fname in os.listdir(basepath):
                path = os.path.join(basepath, fname)
                if os.path.isdir(path):
                        if fname == asked_name:
                                print(path)
```

Comment: It should be `if asked_name in fname`. Other than that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you want to scan the "d:" disk, you can code as:

```
import os
dir="d:\\"
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(dir):
    for a_dir in dirs:
        if ("Server" in a_dir) and ("Jobs" in a_dir) and ("2016" in a_dir):
            print os.path.join(root,a_dir)
```